error File ended while scanning use of \BR@@lbibitem created by revtex4-2 and pagebackref option in hyperref
I have a large file that uses bibtex to create references. I benefit from the option \usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref} since it makes it easier to find the pages where a particular reference is discussed. I tried to switch from \documentclass{article} to \documentclass{revtex4-2} but got the error ! File ended while scanning use of \BR@@lbibitem. I narrowed the error down to the pagebackref option in the hyperref package. Thus, revtex4-2 and pagebackref do not work well together.
The minimal working example reads:
TEX FILE (main.tex):
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\cite{myref}
\bibliography{allrefs}
\end{document}

BIB FILE (all_refs.bib):
@article{myref,
title   = {title},
author  = {author},
year    = 2024,
journal = journal,}


Does anyone understand why this is happening ?
Is there a way to make pagebackref work with revtex4-2?

Thanks in advance !

The log file would have shown which file ended, but it is probably the .aux  file. delete that and try again.

@DavidCarlisle no, the problem is that the bbl has no empty lines between between the bibitem entries, and backref needs them. I don't think that this can be corrected without changing the bst.

@UlrikeFischer ah backref is such a hack, who wrote that....

Indeed, deleting the .aux file did nothing to my compilation.
Regarding the .bbl, I will not be able to do such editing. I dont think I understand enough to go there. Just out of curiosity, should it have empty lines between \bibfield ?
Thx anyway.

no there should be empty lines before every \bibitem command and also before \end{bibliography}. But I don't think that this is enough, I get stray periods if I do this.


\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{myref}
\cite{myref2}
\bibliography{allrefs}
\end{document}


@article{myref,
title   = {title},
author  = {author},
year    = 2024,
journal = journal,}
@article{myref2,
title   = {title2},
author  = {author},
year    = 2024,
journal = journal,}


backref assumes there is a blank line to detect the end of the entry to insert the reference list, the revtex style does not add one.
Simpler than modifying the bibtex, just edit the generated bbl.
After running pdflatex and bibtex, before running pdflatex again edit the .bbl file and replace the
\BibitemShut {NoStop}%

line that appears at the end of the entry by a full stop and blank line
.


Then re-run pdflatex twice and get the output above.
The full bbl file to go with the above example (I added a second \cite for testing) is
%apsrev4-2.bst 2019-01-14 (MD) hand-edited version of apsrev4-1.bst
%Control: key (0)
%Control: author (8) initials jnrlst
%Control: editor formatted (1) identically to author
%Control: production of article title (0) allowed
%Control: page (0) single
%Control: year (1) truncated
%Control: production of eprint (0) enabled
\begin{thebibliography}{2}%
\makeatletter
\providecommand \@ifxundefined [1]{%
 \@ifx{#1\undefined}
}%
\providecommand \@ifnum [1]{%
 \ifnum #1\expandafter \@firstoftwo
 \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi
}%
\providecommand \@ifx [1]{%
 \ifx #1\expandafter \@firstoftwo
 \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi
}%
\providecommand \natexlab [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \enquote  [1]{``#1''}%
\providecommand \bibnamefont  [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \bibfnamefont [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \citenamefont [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \href@noop [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \href [0]{\begingroup \@sanitize@url \@href}%
\providecommand \@href[1]{\@@startlink{#1}\@@href}%
\providecommand \@@href[1]{\endgroup#1\@@endlink}%
\providecommand \@sanitize@url [0]{\catcode `\\12\catcode `\$12\catcode
  `\&12\catcode `\#12\catcode `\^12\catcode `\_12\catcode `\%12\relax}%
\providecommand \@@startlink[1]{}%
\providecommand \@@endlink[0]{}%
\providecommand \url  [0]{\begingroup\@sanitize@url \@url }%
\providecommand \@url [1]{\endgroup\@href {#1}{\urlprefix }}%
\providecommand \urlprefix  [0]{URL }%
\providecommand \Eprint [0]{\href }%
\providecommand \doibase [0]{https://doi.org/}%
\providecommand \selectlanguage [0]{\@gobble}%
\providecommand \bibinfo  [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \bibfield  [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \translation [1]{[#1]}%
\providecommand \BibitemOpen [0]{}%
\providecommand \bibitemStop [0]{}%
\providecommand \bibitemNoStop [0]{.\EOS\space}%
\providecommand \EOS [0]{\spacefactor3000\relax}%
\providecommand \BibitemShut  [1]{\csname bibitem#1\endcsname}%
\let\auto@bib@innerbib\@empty
%</preamble>
\bibitem [{\citenamefont {author}(2024{\natexlab{a}})}]{myref}%
  \BibitemOpen
  \bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibnamefont {author}},\ }\bibfield
  {title} {\bibinfo {title} {title},\ }\href@noop {} {\  (\bibinfo {year}
  {2024}{\natexlab{a}})}.

\bibitem [{\citenamefont {author}(2024{\natexlab{b}})}]{myref2}%
  \BibitemOpen
  \bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibnamefont {author}},\ }\bibfield
  {title} {\bibinfo {title} {title2},\ }\href@noop {} {\  (\bibinfo {year}
  {2024}{\natexlab{b}})}.

\end{thebibliography}%


Copy, in the working directory, the bibstyle apsrev4-2.bst. You find it in TeX Live at
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/revtex/apsrev4-2.bst

Change line 2012 from "\bibitem " to newline$ "\bibitem " and line 3518 from { newline$ to > { newline$ newline$. Here's the diff
2012c2012
<   "\bibitem "
---
>   newline$ "\bibitem "
3518c3518
< { newline$
---
> { newline$ newline$

I added a second reference in order to make sure that the patch is successful.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{myref,
  title   = {title},
  author  = {author},
  year    = 2024,
  journal = journal,
}
@article{myref2,
  title   = {title2},
  author  = {author2},
  year    = 2024,
  journal = journal2,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{revtex4-2}

\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\bibitemNoStop}{}% remove for production version

\begin{document}

\cite{myref} \cite{myref2}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}

The resulting .bbl file is then correct
%apsrev4-2.bst 2019-01-14 (MD) hand-edited version of apsrev4-1.bst
%Control: key (0)
%Control: author (8) initials jnrlst
%Control: editor formatted (1) identically to author
%Control: production of article title (0) allowed
%Control: page (0) single
%Control: year (1) truncated
%Control: production of eprint (0) enabled
\begin{thebibliography}{2}%
\makeatletter
\providecommand \@ifxundefined [1]{%
 \@ifx{#1\undefined}
}%
\providecommand \@ifnum [1]{%
 \ifnum #1\expandafter \@firstoftwo
 \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi
}%
\providecommand \@ifx [1]{%
 \ifx #1\expandafter \@firstoftwo
 \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi
}%
\providecommand \natexlab [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \enquote  [1]{``#1''}%
\providecommand \bibnamefont  [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \bibfnamefont [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \citenamefont [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \href@noop [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \href [0]{\begingroup \@sanitize@url \@href}%
\providecommand \@href[1]{\@@startlink{#1}\@@href}%
\providecommand \@@href[1]{\endgroup#1\@@endlink}%
\providecommand \@sanitize@url [0]{\catcode `\\12\catcode `\$12\catcode
  `\&12\catcode `\#12\catcode `\^12\catcode `\_12\catcode `\%12\relax}%
\providecommand \@@startlink[1]{}%
\providecommand \@@endlink[0]{}%
\providecommand \url  [0]{\begingroup\@sanitize@url \@url }%
\providecommand \@url [1]{\endgroup\@href {#1}{\urlprefix }}%
\providecommand \urlprefix  [0]{URL }%
\providecommand \Eprint [0]{\href }%
\providecommand \doibase [0]{https://doi.org/}%
\providecommand \selectlanguage [0]{\@gobble}%
\providecommand \bibinfo  [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \bibfield  [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \translation [1]{[#1]}%
\providecommand \BibitemOpen [0]{}%
\providecommand \bibitemStop [0]{}%
\providecommand \bibitemNoStop [0]{.\EOS\space}%
\providecommand \EOS [0]{\spacefactor3000\relax}%
\providecommand \BibitemShut  [1]{\csname bibitem#1\endcsname}%
\let\auto@bib@innerbib\@empty
%</preamble>

\bibitem [{\citenamefont {author}(2024)}]{myref}%
  \BibitemOpen
  \bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibnamefont {author}},\ }\bibfield
  {title} {\bibinfo {title} {title},\ }\href@noop {} {\  (\bibinfo {year}
  {2024})}\BibitemShut {NoStop}%

\bibitem [{\citenamefont {author2}(2024)}]{myref2}%
  \BibitemOpen
  \bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibnamefont {author2}},\ }\bibfield
  {title} {\bibinfo {title} {title2},\ }\href@noop {} {\  (\bibinfo {year}
  {2024})}\BibitemShut {NoStop}%

\end{thebibliography}%

with the blank lines at their place. And the output is as expected.

When preparing the final version, you won't need pagebackref, so just rename the local copy of apsrev4-2.bst, remove the pagebackref option, the redefinition of \bibitemStop and recompile.
Next, complain with the maintainers of revtex4-2, because blank lines after \bibitem entries are always expected.

the periods on the lines after the entries are wrong. They should go before the backref entries as in Davids answer.

@UlrikeFischer I'd not bother, as per the OP, this is just a temporary fix during document preparation, not for the final version. I see no period, though.

look at your screenshot: https://i.sstatic.net/KPQvntPG.png

@UlrikeFischer OK, removed them.
